# Form submit validation via fancybox modal & jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, fancybox

I want a generic form validation that opens a fancybox modal pop-up, asking yes or no. I want it to work even if there are multiple forms.

Why is the form not submitted?

The HTML - Form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://192.168.0.4/jojo_cms/content/upload-delete" class="submit-confirm" id='upload-delete-form-1'>
    <input type="hidden" value="enrouleur-motorise-vektor-1-pour-couverture-a-barre-1-l.jpg" name="filename">
    <button name="submit" class="link" type="submit" value="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

The HTML - Modal pop-up:

```
<div id="fancybox-confirm" style="display:none;">
    <p>Sure ?</p>
    <p class="tar">
        <button type="button" class="btn"  id="fancybox-confirm-no" >No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  id="fancybox-confirm-yes" >Yes</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

The jQuery :

```
//creating a 'confirmed' attr = 0 for the forms and defining submit handler
$('form.submit-confirm[id]').attr('confirmed','0').submit(function(e){      

    if($(this).attr('confirmed') == '0') //the form is not confirmed yet
    {
        //setting the target-form attr of the 'Yes' button
        $('#fancybox-confirm-yes').attr('target-form',$(this).attr('id'));          

        //opening the fancybox
        $.fancybox.open({
            src  : '#fancybox-confirm',
            type : 'inline'
        });
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
            console.log('valid!'); //shown in the console when I click 'Yes'
            return; //validating the submission, not working...
    }

});

//The Yes button handler
$('#fancybox-confirm-yes').click(function(){
    if(!!$(this).attr('target-form'))
    {
        formSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('target-form');
        $(formSelector).attr('confirmed','1').submit();
    }
});
```

Thanks !

Comment: If i click 'Yes', close the fancybox, and then submit the form via the regular "delete" submit button, it works...

Comment: Solved ! The submit button name "submit" is what interferred !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ! The submit button name "submit" is what interferred !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simplify the logic, like so:

Create forms having simple buttons (instead of `submit`).

```
<form method="post" action="" class="submit-confirm" id='upload-delete-form-1'>
    <input type="hidden" value="1.jpg" name="filename">
    <button name="delete" class="link" type="button">Delete</button>
</form>
```

The same modal

```
<div id="fancybox-confirm" style="display:none;">
  <p>Sure ?</p>
  <p class="tar">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="fancybox-confirm-no" data-fancybox-close>No</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="fancybox-confirm-yes">Yes</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('form.submit-confirm[id] button.link').on('click', function(e) {
  $("#fancybox-confirm-yes").data('form-id', $(this).parent().attr('id'));

  $.fancybox.open({
    src  : '#fancybox-confirm',
    type : 'inline'
  });
});

$("#fancybox-confirm-yes").on('click', function() {
  $("#" +  $(this).data('form-id')).submit();
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYPypO?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks but I want the HTML working even if I have not jquery or fancybox.